# How Can I Manage Session Data in Node.js Without Using the Request Scope?

Tags: node.js, routes, session-management

I've been experimenting with several flavors of session management in Node.js: `node-session`, `express-session`, etc. These are configured in app.js, and implemented at the request level (e.g., `req.session`) in the routes.

To use session management to say, check that a visitor has authenticated, I need to perform a check (e.g., `req.session.isLoggedIn == true`) on each of the routes to enforce login access. Here's an example:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.status == undefined) { 
    res.redirect('/login');
    }
  else { 
    res.render('index', { 
      pageTitle: 'Index',
      pageID: 'index'
    });
  }
});
```

That means each `.get()` and `.post()` will have this check. It will certainly work, but is there a way I can write it once somehwere, say in app.js, that will cover all requests?

Answer (score 0):

The express middleware is exactly what you're looking for,
Please see http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Hi. I'm using expressjs. The code above is from one of the app route files.

Comment: So did you read about the "middleware" stuff yet? I thought that would fit your requirement.